# Neither stemmer nor lemmatizer seem to work very well, what should I do?

Tags: python, wordnet, stemming, lemmatization, countvectorizer

I am new to text analysis and am trying to create a bag of words model(using sklearn's CountVectorizer method). I have a data frame with a column of text with words like 'acid', 'acidic', 'acidity', 'wood', 'woodsy', 'woody'.

I think that 'acid' and 'wood' should be the only words included in the final output, however neither stemming nor lemmatizing seems to accomplish this.

Stemming produces 'acid','wood','woodi',woodsi'
and lemmatizing produces a worse output of  'acid'  'acidic'    'acidity'   'wood'  'woodsy'    'woody'. I assume this is due to the part of speech not being specified accurately although I am not sure where this specification should go. I have included it in the line `X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'],'a')` (I believe that most of the words should be adjectives) however, it does not make a difference in the output.

What can I do to improve the output?

My full code is below;

```
!pip install nltk
nltk.download('omw-1.4')  
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
```

Data Frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['text']=['acid', 'acidic', 'acidity', 'wood', 'woodsy', 'woody']
```

CountVectorizer with Stemmer:

```
analyzer = CountVectorizer().build_analyzer()
stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def stemmed_words(doc):
    return (stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',analyzer=stemmed_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])
df_bow_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df_bow_sklearn.head()
```

CountVectorizer with Lemmatizer:

```
analyzer = CountVectorizer().build_analyzer()
stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemed_words(doc):
    return(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',analyzer=lemed_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'],'a')
df_bow_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df_bow_sklearn.head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a simple under-performing issue with the wordnetlemmatizer and the stemmer.

Try different ones like...
Stemmers:

- Porter ( -> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer)
- Lancaster (-> from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer)

Lemmatizers:

- spacy ( -> import spacy)
- IWNLP ( -> from spacy_iwnlp import spaCyIWNLP)
- HanTa ( -> from HanTa import HanoverTagger /Note: is more or less trained for german language)

Had the same issue and switching to a different Stemmer and Lemmatizer solved the issue. For closer instruction on how to propperly implement the stemmers and lemmatizers, a quick search on the web reveals good examples on all cases.